# Array support for the original bash in MacOS 10.4.0?

Tags: macos, bash, array

I'm writing a bash script using simple array operations like:
`testarray=("First Name" "Second Name" "Third Name") ;
for i in "${testarray[@]}" ;
do
  echo "$i" ; 
done`

What bash version number came with that original release? 10.4.11 shows me more or less `2.05b.0(1)-release, copyright 2002.`

I tested it on my MacOS 10.4.11 and since I saw the 2.05b vrsion, I kinda freaked out since it's very old even for 10.4.11... 10.4.0 is likely sub 2.0. Is my script backward compatible with 10.4.0?

Someone here will probably throw it into a ppc virtual machine or something. It doesn't have to be exactly 10.4.0, but closer is better. I can't tell if Apple's documentation is correct but it has the exact version number in the [online manpages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.4/man1/bash.1.html) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consult [www.opensource.apple.com](http://www.opensource.apple.com/) to examine the open source components used in the various releases of Mac OS X.

[10.4 (.0)](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-104/) included “bash-44.2”; its CHANGES file indicates that it is 2.05b.

[10.4.11 on x86](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-10411x86/) and
[10.4.11 on PPC](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-10411ppc/) both included “bash-44.5”; CHANGES say it is 2.05b.

The code differences between Apple’s bash-44.2 and -44.5 are very minimal: added `volatile` to one variable and changed the SIGWINCH handling a bit.

Farther back, [10.2 (.0)](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-102/) included “bash-23”; CHANGES says it is 2.05a.

Bash is not listed as a component of [10.1](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-101/) or [10.0](http://www.opensource.apple.com/release/mac-os-x-100/).

It looks like (according to [NEWS](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS)) arrays were introduced as a new feature in bash-2.0, so it looks like you are safe back to at least Mac OS X 10.2.

Comment: +1. Very useful information for now and for me to look at Darwin later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a 10.4.0 system handy; will you settle for 10.3.9?  It came with bash version 2.05b.0(1)-release, so I think you're safe.

Edit: I found some of my old notes, and if they're correct version OS X version 10.2.8 came with bash version 2.05a.0(1)-release.  So they've been using bash v2 for a while...

Oh, and I tested your array code on 10.3.9 and it worked as expected.